# What is issue in Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fire below query...

Is there any problem in it?

```
delete from user_role 
WHERE user_id in (
    select u.user_id from user u, user_role ur 
    where u.USER_ID=ur.USER_ID and ur.ROLE_ID=4 and u.USER_ID not in (
        select user_id from referrers));
```

Comment: I think you cannot use `SELECT user_role` inside `DELETE FROM user_role`...

Comment: What error are you getting? From a quick look it seems like it should execute, but I'd expect it to be very slow if you've got a lot of data.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a test datebase :)

Comment: I think Marco is right...
It was giving error "Error 7/5/2012 12:31:50 PM 0:00:00.000 MySQL Database Error: You can't specify target table 'user_role' for update in FROM clause 55 0
"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the manual section on [`DELETE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html):

> Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

You can instead use the multiple-table form of `DELETE` and [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) together your tables:

```
DELETE user_role
FROM   user_role
  INNER JOIN user_id   USING (USER_ID)
  LEFT  JOIN referrers USING (USER_ID)
WHERE user_role.ROLE_ID = 4 AND referrers.USER_ID IS NULL
```